# Handling composite keys in db table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a table called UsersInRoles with 2 X foreign keys as a composite key which doubles up as the primary key for this 2 column table. Just for resolving many-to-many. So within Entity Framework 6 I have the dal classes.

```
public partial class User
{
    public User()
    {
        this.Roles = new HashSet<Role>();
    }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int ApplicationId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public bool IsAnonymous { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime LastActivityDate { get; set; }

    public virtual Application Application { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}

 public partial class Role
{
    public Role()
    {
        this.Users = new HashSet<User>();
    }

    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public int ApplicationId { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual Application Application { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

So I need to get at the fields within my composite table. I wondered if anyone can provide me with assistance on how to resolve this within OnModelCreating in the dbcontext. So that I can then do something with hasKeys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need to change the Id's name or the table's name you can do that with this configuration:

```
   modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
               .HasMany(u => u.Roles)
               .WithMany(r => r.Users)
               .Map(cs =>
                        {
                            cs.MapLeftKey("UserRefId");
                            cs.MapRightKey("RoleRefId");
                            cs.ToTable("UsersInRoles");
                        });
```

Now if you need to get access explicitly to the [junction table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) or you need to add it new columns, unfortunately you'll need to map it as part of your model.

```
public partial class User
{
    public User()
    {
        this.Roles = new HashSet<Role>();
    }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    //...
    public virtual ICollection<UsersInRoles> Roles { get; set; }
}

public partial class Role
{
    public Role()
    {
        this.Users = new HashSet<User>();
    }

    public int RoleId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UsersInRoles> Users { get; set; }
}

public class UsersInRoles
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0),ForeignKey("User")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1),ForeignKey("Role")]
    public int RoleId { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }

   //add new properties here
}
```

If you prefer use Fluent Api, then remove the data annotations and add these configurations in the `OnModelCreating` method on your context:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UsersInRoles>()
    .HasKey(ur=> new { ur.UserId, ur.RoleId}); 

modelBuilder.Entity<UsersInRoles>()
    .HasRequired(ur=> ur.User)
    .WithMany(u => u.Roles)
    .HasForeignKey(ur=> ur.UserId);

modelBuilder.Entity<UsersInRoles>()
    .HasRequired(ur=> ur.Role)
    .WithMany(u => u.Users)
    .HasForeignKey(ur=> ur.RoleId);
```